# Snowflake invalid property scaling multicluster warehouses not enabled

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have recently completed a workshop utilizing Snowflake and Tableau.

In snowflake, I am getting the following error when running code to "create or replace the warehouse"

SQL compilation error: invalid property 'SCALING_POLICY'; feature 'MULTI_CLUSTER_WAREHOUSES' not enabled

Have others encountered this as well?
C

Comment: can you share your full sql query?

Answer (score 3):

If your query looks like this:

```sql
create or replace warehouse my_wh 
warehouse_size=large 
initially_suspended=true
scaling_policy=standard
;
```

then remove the `scaling_policy` line, that feature is for Snowflake Enterprise edition or higher, and you might be working within the Standard edition.